# jquery pjax not working when I reload the page. Head footer other boy content gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pjax

I have facing a problem when I using the https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax everything working fine. But there is a issue after navigate other section and reload
Here is the following code base. index.html code down below

```
<h1>My Site</h1>
   <div class="navcont">
       Go to <a class="click" href="one-tpl.html">one</a>
       Go to <a class="click" href="two-tpl.html">two</a>
       Go to <a class="click" href="three-tpl.html">two</a> 
   </div>
<div class="container" id="pjax-container"></div>
```

And here is my js code

```
$(document).pjax('a.click', '#pjax-container', { 
    timeout: 3000
});
```

But when I navigate the "two-tpl.html" and reload the page then h1, div.navcont is gone. How will I solve this.

Comment: how have you tried to fix your code to solve your problem? Any self research for fixing this?

Comment: I have research about that $_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"]. but that also not working.

Comment: You should defintely put that sentence into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of pjax() method (#pjax-container) in your js code is the part of page that its content will be displayed after redirect, so you have to put your div.navcont into #pjax-container if you want it to be displayed.

```
<div class="container" id="pjax-container">

    <h1>My Site</h1>
    <div class="navcont">
        Go to <a class="click" href="one-tpl.html">one</a>
        Go to <a class="click" href="two-tpl.html">two</a>
        Go to <a class="click" href="three-tpl.html">two</a> 
    </div>

</div>
```

By the way, it's another idea to add #pjax-container ID to [body] tag of your pages.